# ionic : generated apk is not working anymore

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, apk, command-line-interface

I'm currently making an iOS/Android project on ionic and I am experiencing some troubles with the build. At first the apk was working (at least on my device) but when I tried to make it work on older Android versions (as it should) it stopped working anymore. Sometimes the `ionic build  android` command does not generate anything at all ! And when it does and I put the apk on my device (the *android-x86-debug* one), it goes :

[image]

Here a piece of my config.xml :

```
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="19+"/>
  <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect"/>
  <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded"/>
  <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true"/>
```

I have already tried to remove and add again my android platform but nothing changed. Any advices :) ?

EDIT :

After running command `ionic run android -c -l -s`

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.472 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Users/Mowso/Documents/project/mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-debug.apk
Using apk: C:/Users/Mowso/Documents/project/mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-armv7-debug.apk
LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

So I tried to run *android-armv7-debug.apk* on my device, the installation worked but now it goes "Application Error The connection to the server was unsuccessful". I am actually quite surprise, considering that first versions of my app was installed thanks to the *android-x86-debug.apk*. Now it sounds like a complete different problem.

(`ionic run android` command is still working just fine)

Comment: try using `ionic run android -c -l -s` and check log in terminal..!

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment :) What am I supposed to look after ? @the_mahasagar

Comment: @Mowso You got some update about this issue?

Comment: @MiqdadAli I don't recall how I solved this

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your app from phone and then make build and install .
There is some package issue.

Comment: I'm doing this everytime. Uninstall the app, test the run command, uninstall again from device, test the generated apk then boum, error.

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned app won't install on some mobile devices.
The app must be signed, to do that follow as per given in this link:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Also try

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android@5.1.0
```

then

```
ionic build android
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.
I also get the same problem. Just start some example ionic project and build it on android but whenever I install on real device (marshmallow version), **Application not Installed**.

Previously my build apps name is android-x86-debug.apk and android-armv7-debug.apk so far I explore and get info that those double built apk because of crosswalk-plugin. So, i do this task:

1. Remove crosswalk plugin from the project
2. Remove android platform from the project & add new android platform
3. Rebuild the project and I get app-debug.apk
4. Transfer to device and install. And those apk installed and running well on my device

Wish, this will help you. Thanks